# Query to find distinct string to agregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, distinct, string-aggregation

I have a database table named `logoninfo`. Below is the schema.

```
   Record ID|User ID | Computer ID |LOGON_TIME|LOGOFF_TIME
```

If the logoff time is 0 then the user is currently logged in the computer .
The user name is in separate table named "user" with schema

```
   user id  | user name
```

The computer name is in separate table named "computer" with schema

```
    computer id | computer name
```

I need to have a report which has user name and its corresponding currently logged on computers (separated by comma)

```
        user name | computer names
```

I used the below query but it results in duplicate computers in some cases (same computer shown more than once).

```
select user.name as USER_NAME,
    userLogon."comps" as COMPUTERS
from user
    inner join (
        select user_id as "user_resource",
            string_agg(compRes.name, ' ,') as "comps"
        from logoninfo
            inner join computer compRes on logoninfo.computer_id = compRes.computer_id
        where logoninfo.logoff_time = 0
        group by logoninfo.user_id
    ) userLogon on userLogon."user_resource" = user.user_id
```

So I tried to add `distinct` to `string_agg` function, but it is not possible in SQL Server .

Please help me with query to the required report.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would make this clearer. DDL+DML would make it awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. You can remove `#` sign, it means that I've used a temporary table.

```sql
SELECT u.name as [USER_NAME]
     , l.comps as [COMPUTERS]
FROM #user u
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(c.name, ', ') as [comps]
  FROM (
    SELECT c.name
    FROM #logoninfo l
    JOIN #computer c ON l.computer_id = c.computer_id
    WHERE l.user_id = u.user_id
      AND l.logoff_time = 0
    GROUP BY c.name
  ) c
) l
```

And the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this.

Filter early and aggregate using string_agg

```
select userLogon.user_resource
         , string_agg(compRes.name, ' ,') as concat_computer
    from (
          select distinct 
                  user_id as "user_resource",
                  compRes.name as "comps"
            from logoninfo
            join computer compRes 
              on logoninfo.computer_id = compRes.computer_id
            join user us
              on logonginfo.user_id=us.user_id
            where logoninfo.logoff_time = 0
          ) userLogon
  group by userLogon.user_resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a correlalated subquery, or a lateral join:

```
select u.*, c.*
from users u
cross apply (
    select string_agg(name) as all_computers
    from (
        select distinct c.name
        from computer c
        inner join logoninfo li on li.computer_id = c.computer_id
        where li.user_id = u.user_id and li.logoff_time = 0
    ) c
) c
```